# Making a login page using data from a txt file

Tags: python, file, authentication, txt

I am currently creating a program that creates a login page and asks for a username and password. Then user inputs the username and password and if it is from the data file, it logs you in. Whenever I input the first two users, it says the users do not exist even though they do. When I input the 3rd or 4th user, It works. please Help.

admins.txt =
User1, 24680
User2, 13579
User3, 56789

```
print("1. Administrator Log-In Portal")
print("2. Make a Reservation")
print("3. Close Application")
choice = int(input("What would you like to do?"))
if (choice == 1):
    file = open("admins.txt", "r")
    print("Administrator Login Portal")
    print("--------------------------")
    username = input("Enter Username:")
    password = input("Enter Password:")
    for line in file:
        a,b = line.split(",")
        b = b.strip( )
    if(a == username and b == password):
        print("Login Successful!")            
    else:
        print("Wrong username/password")
        file.close( )
```

Comment: Can you add the input data and admins.txt data in the question for better understanding.

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code does not run.

Comment: Is that good? I input each of the users as my input. For example, for username I input User1 and for the password I input 24680 but It says invalid user/pass. It does the same for the 2nd user but for the 3rd user it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're looping over the items and storing the last passworld/username in the variables a and b, only the last user will work.
I recommend using a dictionary to store the usernames and passwords.

```
file = open("admins.txt", "r")
    print("Administrator Login Portal")
    print("--------------------------")
    username = input("Enter Username:")
    password = input("Enter Password:")
    login_info = {}
    for line in file:
        name, password = line.split(",")
        password = password.strip()
        login_info[name] = password
    if username in login_info.keys():
        if(login_info[name] == password):
            print("Login Successful!")
        else:
            print("Wrong password")
            file.close()
    else:
        print("Wrong username")
        file.close()
```

Comment: you're welcome!

 As an improvement to your program, I recommend to encrypt admins.txt, because now anyone can read the file and use someones login.